# Tried to move windows users folder to another dive but messed up bad

Tags: windows, windows-10, profile

I was following this tutorial video https://youtu.be/88isPOPkscE
So basically what I was trying to do was to move users folder to another dive.
As the video was telling I went to regedit and did want it said upto changing the location of profile directory and public to the dive I want I think I wrote it wrong because after writing the new location and creating a account when I tried to login i failed it said that user profile service failed and now I can't log in to change the location to the correct format and also all my other account are now gone

Comment: First, that's a really old video. The details even say there's a new version that's not nearly so old. Second, don't move your users folder. You can move your documents and other things easily and without damaging your system, but moving your entire user folder will break things, as you've experienced now. You can create new users, and the copy back the user data you moved over to the new profile folders, to recover from this.

Comment: How I can I create a new user if I can't log in  every time when I try to log in it says user profile service failed I think that because I changed the location of profile directory and public

Comment: Have you tried a repair install?